# C++: strange division output

Tags: c++, division

I have the following codes:

```
    int x = arr[arr.size() -1] - arr[0];
    int n = arr.size();
    int dx = x/n;
    int dy = (arr[arr.size() -1] - arr[0])/arr.size();
    std::cout << dx << "  " << dy << std::endl;
```

when my `arr = [15, 13, 12]`, I got `dx = -1`, but `dy = 1431655764` (`arr is vector<int>`)

Why `dx` and `dy` are different? Thanks!

Comment: Your codes are not complete - but I suspect you are doing someting with undefined behaviour. -  Add the surrouding  code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why `dx` and `dy` are different?

For `dy`, note that the return type of [`std::vector::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is `std::vector::size_type`, which is an unsigned integer type. Then the result of `(arr[arr.size() -1] - arr[0])/arr.size()` is unsigned too. The result is [overflowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows), then assigned to `dy` with type `int`.

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed *modulo 2<sup>n</sup>*
>    where n is the number of bits in that particular integer. E.g. for `unsigned int`, adding one to `UINT_MAX` gives `​0`​, and subtracting one from `​0​` gives `UINT_MAX`.

For `dx`, `arr.size()` is assigned to `n` (whose type is `int`) firstly, then gets calculated as `x/n`, whose result is `int` too. Then the result is assigned to `dx` and anything is fine.

Comment: "_Why dx and dy are different?_" - As a headline and the breakdown to explain it had been nice.